SSH auth with server, disable password login
I'm trying to connect to a server I host on my local network, using SSH publickey authentication. I'm using the 1password SSH agent.
When I make a request (using -vvv for verbose logging) I can see SSH finds the SSH keys in 1password because they are listed out:
Will attempt key: GitHub SSH Key <<key fingerprint...>
Will attempt key: My Server Key <<key fingerprint...>

But I do not see any lines printed that state Offering public key so I believe the keys are not being tried.
My config file:
# ~/.ssh/config

Host *
    IdentityAgent "~/.1password/agent.sock" 
    
    # Auth methods
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    DSAAuthentication no
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
    HostbasedAuthentication no
    KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PreferredAuthentications publickey

Host myserver.lan
    User root

To add the public key from 1password to the server, I tried both ssh-copy-id and manual. The line in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server matched the value of cat pub-key-exported-from-1password.pub.

I feel like I'm missing something obvios. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please run ssh with the "-vvv" option to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output.

Answering my own question here!
After some more debugging, I found that the connection works when I move/remove my .ssh/config file.
I stepped through the config file gradually built it back up, and found that the following line was the issue:
    DSAAuthentication no

DSAAuthentication is mentioned in multiple sources online, but it not supported by the version of ssh shipped in macOS 14.2.
The fix then, was to remove that line. My config now looks like:
Host *
    # ...
    
    # The following are disabled because we don't use them generally.
    # These could be re-eneabled on a per-host basis if necessary.
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    # DSAAuthentication no              # Note: DEPRECATED
    # RSAAuthentication no              # Note: DEPRECATED
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
    HostbasedAuthentication no
    KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes            # Default = yes
    PreferredAuthentications "publickey"

